# "No attribute" error in the Django Shell through ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a models.py file

```
from django.db import models

class PersonalInformation(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name

class OrderInformation(models.Model):

    personalInformation = models.ForeignKey(PersonalInformation,
                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_name = models.TextField(blank = False)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 8, decimal_places = 2)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name
```

in the shell am running following command:

```
from web.models import PersonalInformation, OrderInformation
k = PersonalInformation.objects.get(pk = 1)
```

it outputs

```
<PersonalInformation: John>
```

which is correct. However, which I do this

```
k.orderInformation_set.all()
```

it get the error

```
AttributeError: 'PersonalInformation' object has no attribute 'orderInformation_set'
```

Isn't Django supposed to generate this orderInformation_set field automatically?

dir(k) outputs following:

```
>>> dir(k)

['DoesNotExist', 'MultipleObjectsReturned', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_check_column_name_clashes', '_check_constraints', '_check_field_name_clashes', '_check_fields', '_check_id_field', '_check_index_together', '_check_indexes', '_check_local_fields', '_check_long_column_names', '_check_m2m_through_same_relationship', '_check_managers', '_check_model', '_check_model_name_db_lookup_clashes', '_check_ordering', '_check_property_name_related_field_accessor_clashes', '_check_single_primary_key', '_check_swappable', '_check_unique_together', '_do_insert', '_do_update', '_get_FIELD_display', '_get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD', '_get_next_or_previous_in_order', '_get_pk_val', '_get_unique_checks', '_meta', '_perform_date_checks', '_perform_unique_checks', '_save_parents', '_save_table', '_set_pk_val', '_state', 'check', 'clean', 'clean_fields', 'date_error_message', 'delete', 'first_name', 'from_db', 'full_clean', 'get_deferred_fields', 'id', 'last_name', 'objects', 'orderinformation_set', 'pk', 'prepare_database_save', 'refresh_from_db', 'save', 'save_base', 'serializable_value', 'unique_error_message', 'validate_unique']
```

Comment: Yes - but it doesn't case it like that... do a `dir(k)` and you'll find it

Comment: @JonClements i did dir(k), it didn't help

Comment: Did it not show any variables with a name ending in `_set` that look like the one you want to use?

Comment: I tried even with related_name and still didn't work

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include the output of the `dir(k)` above please? (and the traceback/further describe what "still didn't work" means...)

Comment: it didn't show any variable ends with _set.

Comment: I just edited the post.

Comment: Are you sure you're not doing this the wrong way around... eg: you want to get a Person and then you want to use the _set on that to retrieve all the Orders? If you're getting the first Order then it only ever relates to a Single person so there isn't a collection of them to access (you've already got that by accessing the `personalInformation` attribute on the Order object)...

Comment: I want to update the OrderInformation table which is linked to the PersonalInformation table. Am storing the single person in k and then picking one person ( which is pk = 1) so i can update the OrderInformation table for pk = 1 person. How am supposed to do this? I am following the tutorial on teh Django website and according to it, orderInformation_set field should automatically generate. I couldn't figure out where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Well, `k` isn't a `PersonalInformation` model - you're picking a `ContactInformation` object instead... is that something you tried and its left over and doesn't have any foreign keys? Although your repr of it does show it's a PersonalInformation object, but looking at the attributes of the object - it's not got what the model for PersonalInformation has you've shown...

Comment: sorry it was a typo, k is picking the PersonalInformation model. I updated above as well.

Comment: And have you updated the output of `dir(k)` ?

Comment: Yes, I just updated that as well. I wrote all code again.

Comment: Did you notice `orderinformation_set` there?

Comment: Yes, but why isn't its working?

Comment: Are you using the correct case... `k.orderinformation_set.all()` - otherwise, you'll going to have to explain what you mean by it's not working...

Comment: It is working now. WOW. Thank you so much